# Splitting an unsigned char into two halves for a character

Tags: c++, split, char, unsigned

I have an unsigned char lets say 0x5E which I want to split into two equal parts.
What is the required bit shifts in order to get this done? I did the following to convert hex in unsigned long to two parts

```
unsigned int first_half = (my_long & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32;
unsigned int second_half = my_long & 0x00000000ffffffff;
```

How to go by doing it with the unsigned character. does 32 get replaced by the 8 because its a character.?

Answer (score 0):

The original code does `>> 32` because it tries to shift half of the bits down. `my_long` was a `unsigned long int`, which has 64 bits, so half of that is 32.

A character is a byte, which is 8, so it would be shifted 4 bits.

Comment: @ Leif Messinger LOAF and the 0xffffffff00000000 gets changed to 0xffff0000?

Comment: @AzeemLodhi It would be 0xf0, because a character (for example) is 0x5E and that's one half of it.

Comment: somthing like this unsigned char first_half = (nNum & 0xf0) >> 4;

Comment: unsigned char second_half = nNum & 0x0f; @ Leif

Comment: can you please take a look at the comments

Comment: If nNum is an unsigned char, then yes.
You can print out the hex yourself with `std::printf("%x %x",first_half, second_half)` if you include `cstdio`